# How can I declare several variables within an array directly in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, declaration

I need to declare several variables of the same type (interface) at the time that I declare an array.

I am using it in an Angular 8 project, obviously using typescript.

I have this now:

```
export class GridComponent {

  pizza0: Pizza;
  pizza1: Pizza;
  pizza2: Pizza;
  pizza3: Pizza;
  pizza4: Pizza;
  pizza5: Pizza;

  constructor() {}

}

interface Pizza {
 name: string;
 ingredients: number;
 price: string;
}
```

And I want something like:

```
PizzaList: Array<Pizza> = new Array<Pizza>(pizza0, pizza1, pizza2, pizza3, pizza4, pizza5);


interface Pizza {
 name: string;
 ingredients: number;
 price: string;
}
```

And that each of the variables that I define within the array are declared initially

Comment: What do you mean declared? Initialized as a pizza object? In that case, use a class instead of and interface.

Comment: It is an interface, and I am doing this within an Angular component

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want `pizzaList` to be an array of Pizza objects. You can create that as follows:

```
const pizzaList: Array<Pizza> = [
    { name: 'Margherita', ingredients: 1337, price: 9.99 },
    { name: 'Quattro stagioni', ingredients: 1337, price: 9.99 }
];
```

If you just want to declare it as "An array of pizzas, with length 6", that is not possible. You cannot declare it as a fixed length array of Pizza objects, you can only declare it as an array of pizza objects without specifying the length.

Comment: Yes but, I don't want to initialize them, just declare. So I don't want to put all the properties of each object. I just want to say like "I have an array of 6 pizzas with the type pizza":

PizzaList: Array<Pizza> = new Array<Pizza>(pizza0, pizza1, pizza2, pizza3, pizza4, pizza5);

Comment: That is not possible. You cannot define an array with a statically typed length. You can only say: `PizzaList: Array<Pizza>` to define it as an array of `Pizza` objects. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without initializing the array with `new Array<T>`.

If your values are predefined then you can do it like:

```
PizzaList: Array<Pizza> = [pizza0, pizza1, pizza2, pizza3, pizza4, pizza5];
```

Or you can create them like:

```
PizzaList: Array<Pizza> = [
    new Pizza(/*args*/),
    new Pizza(/*args*/),
    new Pizza(/*args*/)
];
```

Comment: I cannot create like this because Pizza its an Interface, not a class